# LASSO reg in stata (plogit function)

Tags: lambda, lasso-regression

I am new to LASSO method (I understand it is mostly done in R, however I do not know R). So in stata there is a user written code plogit which does lasso ( byTony Brady and Gareth Ambler). Has anyone used that?

If so, my question would be what is the optimum value of lambda (#) ? I have 20 explanatory variables. I put the lambda value 14 and i get 11 coeff. = 0.000, while lambda = 6, I get 4 vars = 0.00

So what would be the optimum value? In the help plogit, it says "Higher values of lambda introduce more penalisation)

Thanks a lot!